# Getting 404 Not Found Error on Ajax Form Submit

Tags: html, ajax, flask

I'm building a Flask webapp, and on my webpage, when the user submits my form, it leads to a 404 error.

I'm certain it has to do with the url: "/get" part of the code below, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
The app is a Chatbot, and if I remove the url: "/get" part, a miniature copy of the website gets put into the chat history where instead I should be getting the reply from the language model.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#messageArea").on("submit", function(event) {
                const date = new Date();
                const hour = date.getHours();
                const minute = date.getMinutes();
                const str_time = hour+":"+minute;
                var rawText = $("#text").val();

                var userHtml = '<div class="d-flex justify-content-end my-4 chatBubble"><div class="msg_container">' + rawText + '<span class="msg_time_send">'+ str_time + 
                    '</span></div></div>';

                $("#text").val("");
                $("#chatArea").prepend(userHtml);

                $.ajax({
                    data: {
                        msg: rawText,
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/get",
                }).done(function(data){
                    var botHtml = '<div class="d-flex justify-content-start my-4 chatBubble"></div><div class="msg_container">'
                        + data + '<span class="msg_time">' + str_time + '</span></div></div>';
                    $("#chatArea").prepend($.parseHTML(botHtml));
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: do you have an endpoint `/get`? `"I'm certain it has to do with the url: "/get" part of the code below, but I'm not sure how to fix it."` - why then send an ajax request to that endpoint? What is the URL that **should** handle these requests?

Comment: This is a single page application so the url shouldn't change at all every time the user interacts with the chatbot. I was following a tutorial so I don't quite understand exactly how to correct this. I imagine the url that should be handling the requests is just the home domain url.

Comment: You are sending an ajax request to `/get` as an endpoint. With no knowledge of your server setup or any rewrite rules or aliases you might have in place nobody, other than your good self, can determine if that endpoint exists. The fact that you have a `404` error suggests that it does not. Can you share the tutorial url that you are following?

Comment: For sure, it's this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70H_7C0kMbI     I also can confirm that I don't have any webpage that corresponds to the /get endpoint. I'm just not sure what to do, whether I have to get rid of it or not.

Comment: I do not wish to watch the entire video but [at this point of the video](https://youtu.be/70H_7C0kMbI?t=191) one can see `/get` referenced in the code. Is that of relevance to how you are approaching this problem? If not, please show where you see `/get` used as an endpoint! I suspect that a small, subtle point has been overlooked - the fact that it says `@app.route("/get",....)` suggests certain serverside configuration is required to configure a suitable endpoint - referred to in most frameworks as a `route`

Comment: I see, the part that corresponds to the code snippet above is at 20:37. I am not sure exactly how ajax and flask interacts together however..

Comment: Somewhere around [this point](https://youtu.be/70H_7C0kMbI?t=99) he discusses routing. I know nothing of Flask and only the basics of Python but I have watched more of the video now so understand better. The above Javascript is fine - it is likely your python `app.py` or whatever where fault lies?